# Create public method on angular component for outside of angular access

Tags: angular, web-component

If I query an angular element in, for example, the DevTools console

```
$> $('app-foo').setSomething('yolo');
```

it doesn't work, telling me that `setSomething` does not exist.

I tried to create an angular component like this

```
@Component({
     selector: 'app-my-component',
     template: 'my component'
})
export class MyComponent {
    @Input()
    setSomething(input: string): void {
        // do magic
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bha3p6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

However, if I compile my component to a web component (using `@angular/elements`) it actually works. But in my current case I'm not going to create a web component and I have to deal with angular components. So the question is, how can I make a method available on the DOM instance? If there is an other way of doing this please let me know as well!

UPDATE: The reason I would like to this this is because I created a web component with @angular/elements called `lib-foo`. This component should receive an other component as follows

```
<lib-foo>
     <an-angular-component></an-angular-component>
</lib-foo>
```

The template from `lib-foo` is just `<slot></slot>` (shadowdom enabled).

From within `lib-foo` I would like to access `an-angular-component`, so I did

```
child = this.element.nativeElement.children[0]; // an-angular-component
contentChild.setSomething('yolo');
```

`lib-foo` should only get children which have a `setSomething` method. But whatever I do to create `an-angular-component` in my other angular project, these components never have that method

Comment: Why do you do it with vanilla JS? It is not safety. Why don't you do this Angular way?

Comment: I've added an update to my post which hopefully explains well why I would like to do this

Comment: In case I correctly understood you, lib-foo is angular component too. Why don't you use there ViewChild and call its method in AfterViewInit lifecycle hook?

Comment: Both are separate projects. The web-component can receive any component, not necessarily an angular component. If you build a Vue app and use my web-component, you need to create a vue-component which has this `setSomething` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably going to get a lot of responses telling you how what you are trying to do is a bad idea. It certainly isn't the best practice, and having to do something like that is a sign that you should reconsider your application's design and architecture.

But if you really must, this is one way to do it:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.css']
})
export class FooComponent {

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    // get the native element and set a function on it
    (elementRef.nativeElement as any).setSomething = this.setSomething
  }

  @Input()
  setSomething(input: string) {
     console.log('set something');
  }
}
```

You can then query the document for the element and call the function on it, i.e. `$('app-foo').setSomething();`

If you are trying to access the child component's method from a parent component, you can use https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren to access them. If you want to use the methods from outside angular, then the snippet above will be what you are looking for.

Comment: very creative and it works like a charm ( [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhrtxf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) )